# Solaris find from file - remove duplicate entries

Tags: linux, command, solaris

I'm trying to see if there is a way to remove duplicates from the search results.
I've tried the following, but, does not remove duplicates.

**Search string**

```
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [SomeFileNamePattern].
```

**command**

> find . -name "logg.mss.log"  | xargs grep -i
>   'log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [.*]' |
>   uniq

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

Found it

> find . -name "logg.mss.log"  | xargs grep -i 'log4j:ERROR Attempted to
>   append to closed appender named [.*]' | sort | uniq